# Smallest subgroup and $\langle a \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition

Gallian says in Chapter 3 of Contemporary Abstract Algebra that

> For any element $a$ of a group $G$, it is useful to think of $\langle a \rangle$ as the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $a$.

But wouldn't this mean the set $\langle a \rangle$ is simply $\{ a, a^{-1}, e \}$?

Comment: If it doesn't contain $a^2$, that isn't a subgroup.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why not?

Comment: It needs to be closed under the group's operation.

Comment: That isn't a group unless $a = a^{-1}$, in which case it would be $\{a, e\}$ only

Comment: @q.Then  Actually that is a group if $a^2 = a^{-1}$.

Comment: Correction, you are right....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set $\{a,a^{-1},e\}$ has an identity and is closed under inverses, but it isn't necessarily closed under the group's operation.

If $H$ is a subgroup and $a \in H$, you also need $a^2=aa\in H$ and $a^3=aaa \in H$ etc. Likewise, you need inverses for all of those elements (i.e. $a^{-1}, a^{-2}, \dots \in H$).

So closure under the group's operation and inverses require at least $\langle a \rangle = \{ a^n \;|\; n \in \mathbb{Z} \} \subseteq H$.

Once you know  $\langle a \rangle$ is itself a subgroup. This shows that it is the *smallest* subgroup containing $a$.

Comment: So what you're saying is that once you have $a$ in the subgroup, you automatically need its powers too because $a * a$ and $a *a * a$, etc. ought to be allowed operations under the group operation?

Comment: A group's operation is associative, has an identity, and inverses...but it also must be *closed*. If $a,b \in G$, then $ab \in G$ as well. So this means $a \in G$ then $a^2=aa \in G$ etc. So *closure* is what is forcing this.

Comment: Ah okay so the set $\{ a, a^{-1}, e \}$ isn't actually a group at all?

Comment: Not in general. For example: let $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then $\{i,i^{-1},e\} = \{i,-i,1\}$ is not a group since multiplication isn't a *closed* binary operation operation on this set ($i^2=-1 \not\in \{i,-i,1\}$. Since we don't have a closed operation, it's not a group.

Comment: On the other hand, it could be. Consider $a=-1$ (with multiplication). Then $\{a,a^{-1},e\}=\{-1,(-1)^{-1},1\} = \{1,-1\}$ which is a perfectly good (cyclic) group (under multiplication). So $\{a,a^{-1},e\}$ can be a group, but usually it isn't. :)

Comment: $\{a,a^{-1},e\}$ is a group if and only if $a^3=e$ or in other words $a^2 = a^{-1}$.  Which can happen.  It can also happen that $a^2 =e$ or $a = a^{-1}$ in which case $<a> = \{a,e\}$.  And if $a = e$ then $<a> = \{e\}$.  If $a^n=e$ then $<a> = \{e,a,a^2,a^3,..... a^{n-1}\}$  But it's also possible that $a^n \ne e$ ever.  e.g. the infinite group of the integers where $<2> = 0, \pm 2, \pm 4,......\pm 2k.....$

Comment: @BillCook I find the simplest explanations are $\mathbb Z_n$ so for $\mathbb Z_{12}$ $4^{3} = 4+4+4=0$ and $<4> = \{0,4,4^{-1}=8\}$.  Furthermore:  $<6> = \{0,6\};<4>=<8>=\{0,4,8\};<3>=<9>=\{0,3,6,9\};<2>=<10>=\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ and $<1>=<5>=<7>=<11>=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\} = \mathbb Z_{12}$.  And we also need to consider $a$ having infinite order, in which case $<a> \cong \mathbb Z$.  Ex.  as a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ the group $<17> = \{$multiples of 17$\}$.

Comment: I find that someone who is unsure about closure, generally has a difficult time navigating multiplicative vs additive notation. So I put multiplicative examples in the above comments. As a side note, writing $4^3$ for $4+4+4$ isn't technically correct. When the operation is addition, additive exponents are written as multiples: $3•4=4+4+4$. This of course is confusing because it looks like multiplication (and as we know computes the same thing). But additive exponent $3•4=4+4+4$ is defined within a *group* of integers mod $n$ whereas $3×4$ requires ring structure.

Comment: That is true.  It is a trade off.  I'm okay with saying $4^3 = 4*4*4$ "for whatever operation $*$" is". So there fore if $*$ is +, then $4^3 = 4+ 4+4$ but I can see how that can be confusing.  Would it be been better if I had said:  If $G = \mathbb Z_{12},+$ then $4^3 = 4*4*4$ where $*$ is modulo addition then....?

Comment: I guess that's ok. But even better is to pick examples avoiding the issue entirely. :)

Comment: On a tangent, I believe the very first text I learned on made a point of hammering home that groups where abstractions and that $<G;*,e>$ with $a^k = a*a*...; e*a=a*e=a; a^{-1}*a = e$ was completely equivalent to $<G,\cdot,1>$ with $a^k = a\circ a \cdot...; 1\cdot a=a\cdot 1=a; a^{-1} \cdot a =1$ and to $<G,+,0>$ with $ka = a+a +...; 0 +  a=a+0=a; -a + a =0$.  To be fair, it *did* balk very strongly at mixing notation.

Comment: Except that additive groups are so much more intuitive than multiplicative groups.  (At least to me they are).  *sigh*.  It is a trade off.

Comment: @fleablood: "$\{a,a^{−1},e\}$ is a group if and only if $a^3=e$ or in other words $a^2=a^{−1}$." — I take issue with the "only if" part. You yourself mention the case $a^2=e$ later; in that case, $\{a,a^{−1},e\}=\{a,e\}$ is a group as well, but in general $a^3=a\ne e$. A correct statement would have been: $\{a,a^{−1},e\}$ is a group if and only if $a^3\in\{e,a\}$.

Comment: @celtschk.  I was taking it as definition/given that if a set is expressed as {a,b,c} that the terms are distinct.  (Which I abused in my own answer).  Feel free to interpret my statement as {$a,a^{-1},e$}$a\ne a^{-1}$ is a group iff $a^2 = a^{-1}$.  Or $\{a,a^{-1},e\} $ is a group iff 1 of the three conditions are met:i) $a^2=a $, in which case $a=a^{-1}=e $, ii)a^2=a^{-1} $ in which case either a=e=a' or they are paiwise distinct yet $a^3=e $, or iii) $a^2=e $ in which case $a=a^{-1} $ and a may or may not equal e.  In any event, the only group with three elements is e,a != e,a^2=a' != a.

Comment: iff a^3 in {a,e} seems unnecessarily confusing to me. {a,a',e} with 3 distinct terms is a group iff a^2=a' seems more straightforward and directly addresses the issue.

Comment: @fleablood: Requiring all mentioned elements in a set as distinct seems wrong to me. Consider for example the set in the answer above: $\{a^n|n\in Z\}$. According to your definition, this would exclude elements of finite order. Or consider the common definition of a pair as $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. You definitely don't want that definition to exclude pairs like $(3,3)$, do you?

Comment: I thought it was clear in context.  It's a matter of (takes off his mathematician hat and puts on his librarian hat-- he is both) prescriptive vs. descriptive.  In context {a,a',e} is descriptive; understood to be three items listed distinctly; {a^n|n in Z} is prescriptive in it is telling you how to define something.  What it'll actually be is unknown until it is examined.

Comment: Wait, that definition of pairs as sets with two elements doesn't work anyway and I most certainly DO want (a,b)!=(b,a).  So (a,b)={a,b} is wrong and ABSOLUTELY (a,a) != {a}.

Comment: " Consider for example the set in the answer above: $\{a^n|n\in Z\}$. According to your definition, this would exclude elements of finite order. " of course not. I don't throw away repeated terms. I keep one representative. But I would claim this definition is redundant. And it is. Which I never said was forbidden. And that's *not* a list of elements.  Its a single description. I merely said a set in list notation in context will likely be presumed to be distinct. It's not a requirement and it'll arguably an assumption. But it's not worth complex convolutions about.

Answer (score 1):

Groups are closed under their operations.  In other words if $a,b \in G$ then we know that $ab \in G$.

So if $a\in <a>$ then we know that $a*a=a^2 \in <a>$ and $a^2*a = a^3 \in <a>$ and inductively we know that $a^2 \in <a>$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.  And as inverses must exist we know $a^{-n} \in G$.

So *in general* the group $<a> = \{.......a^{-3},a^{-2},a^{-1}, e,a,a^2,a^3,....\}$.  But the $a^i$ need not be distinct.  It could be possible for $a^i = a^k;i \ne j$.  An example is $\mathbb Z_6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ under modulo addition.  $2^5 = 2+2+2+2+2 = 4 = 2+2 = 2^2$.  So $\{......2^{-3}=0,2^{-2}=2, 2^{-1}=4, 0, 2, 2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 0,....\} = \{0,2,4\}$ is not infinite.

Now it is possible that $a^k =e$ for some number $k$.  Then $a^{-1} = a^{k-1}$  Example: In $\mathbb Z_6$, $2^3 = 2+2+2= 0$ and $2^{-1} = 4 = 2^{3-1}$.  In this case $<a> = \{0, a, a^2, a^3, .... a^{k-1}\}$. Example $<2> \subset \mathbb Z_{6} = \{0,2,2^2=2^{-1}=4\}$

But it's *also* possible that $a^k \ne e$ for any $k \ne 0$.  In this case $<a> = \{a^n|n \in \mathbb Z\}$.  Example: If the group is $\mathbb Z$ under addition.  Then $<7> = \{0, 7, -7, 14, -14, 21, -21, ....\} = \{7n| n \in \mathbb Z\}$.  Which is infinite.

....

In general.  If $a^n= e$ and $a^k\ne e; 1\le k < n$ we so "the order of $a$" is $n$ and we write it as $|a| = n$.  If no such $n$ exists, we say $|a| = \infty$.

If $|a| = n$ then $<a> =\{0,a, a^2, ....., a^{n-1}\}$.

If $|a| = \infty$ then $<a> = \{a^k|k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Notice $<a>$ always has $|a|$ units.